# Batching calls to server in python with asyncio

Tags: python, asynchronous

I've written this decorator to avoid too many requests to a backend. Did I get it right? Do I need some locks or can I assume some things are atomic / thread safe because this is asyncio?

```
def batch_calls(f):
    """Batches single call into one request.

    Turns `f`, a function that gets a `tuple` of independent requests, into a function
    that gets a single request.
    """
    queue = {}

    async def make_call():
        if not queue:
            return
        await asyncio.sleep(0.1)
        if not queue:
            return
        queue_copy = dict(queue)
        queue.clear()
        try:
            for async_result, result in zip(
                queue_copy.values(), await f(tuple(queue_copy))
            ):
                async_result.set_result(result)
        except Exception as exception:
            for async_result in queue_copy.values():
                async_result.set_exception(exception)

    async def wrapped(hashable_input):
        if hashable_input in queue:
            return await queue[hashable_input]
        async_result = asyncio.Future()
        # Check again because of context switch due to the creation of `asyncio.Future`.
        # TODO(uri): Make sure this is needed.
        if hashable_input in queue:
            return await queue[hashable_input]
        queue[hashable_input] = async_result
        if len(queue) == 1:
            asyncio.create_task(make_call())
        return await async_result

    return wrapped
```

The user might use it like so:

```
@batch_calls
async def call_server(texts: Tuple[Text, ...]):
    return tuple(
        (
            await httpx.post(
                url=SERVICE_URL,
                json={"texts": texts},
            )
        ).json()
    )
```

This code is causing a deadlock on some situations - not easily reproducible.

Comment: Can you also post a more extended context: 1) a sample function `f` definition to which your decorator is applied; 2) sample `hashable_input` value ???

Comment: gave a run example. you can think of hashable_input as a string. ptal